# Obtener peso de archivos alojados en un File Update en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, fileupload

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para subir archivos a servidor
Tengo mi HttpRunTime limitado a 12288 que mas o menos son como 5 archivos
Lo que necesito es capturar el peso total de los archivos en el File Update para validarlo y no salte el error (Se excedió la longitud de solicitud máxima.)

Intente con `int Tamaño = FileUpload.PostedFiles.ContentLength;` Pero no es posible esta sentencia

Saben de alguna manera de hacer el conteo de todos los archivos juntos
De antemano Gracias!!!